# Question On Django Form Models

Tags: django, forms, models

I am working on form models and get this error:
global name 'AdForm' is not defined

In my view I have:

from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django import forms

```
@login_required
def create(request):
    if request.POST:
        ad = AdForm(request.POST)
        if ad.is_valid():
            test = 'valid'
        else:
            test = 'invalid'
    else:
        test = 'none'

    template = loader.get_template('ads/create.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'test': test
    })

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

However it is not picking up my model. My model in my view is:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

TYPE_CHOICES = (
    'Image',
    'Code',
)

SIZE_CHOICES = (
    'Leaderboard',
    'Banner',
    'Skyscraper',
    'Square',
)

class Ad(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    clicks = models.IntegerField()
    media = models.ImageField(upload_to='ads')
    link = models.URLField(null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    expires = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class AdForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ad
```

Does anyone know why it is not picking up the form model?

Thanks from a noob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the top of your view, you need:

```
from .models import AdForm
```

Also, forms usually go in `forms.py`, not with the models.

Comment: Thanks, do I put them in there even if they reference models? And how would I reference my Ad model from models.py in forms.py? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks I was able to import it with from ads.models import Ad